# Hosting multiple Nodejs applications on a single domain

Tags: nginx, node.js

I'm trying to run multiple nodejs applications (using the express framework) all served on the same external port (80) but each under a subdirectory.

E.g. I want...

NodeJsApplication1 to be available at http://www.mydomain.com/NodeJsApplication1

NodeJsApplication2 to be available at http://www.mydomain.com/NodeJsApplication2

etc.

I have tried using Nginx as a proxy with a conf similar to the following.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /NodeJsApplication1/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        rewrite /NodeJsApplication1/(.*) /$1 break;
    }

    location /NodeJsApplication2/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        rewrite /NodeJsApplication2/(.*) /$1 break;
    }
}
```

This works find for accessing the page but it breaks all relative URLs on the returning page. All scripts and css etc are pointing at the root (E.g. www.mydomain.com/styles/main.css).

I know I can use multiple subdomains but don't want to go down that route. I'd prefer to have subfolder proxy so it is all handled in software and I don't need to set up any DNS records for each application.

Is this even possible?

Update

Within the applications themselves all links are using relative paths. For example:

But when rendered the browser treats them as "www.mydomain.com/styles/main.css" rather than "www.mydomain.com/NodeJsApplication1/styles/main.css".

the first being to modify the NodeJS applications to specify a full URL but this requires the application to know the subdirectory that nginx is configured with and it ruins portability to another environment.

Comment: Are you sure they are relative? How do they look like in your html?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with having multiple MEAN apps on the same domain.  I wanted subdirectories instead of having to create a new subdomain for each app.  In addition to adding a rewrite to your Nginx config:

```
rewrite ^/app1/(.*)$ /$1 break;
```

You also need to set your `<base>` tag in the head of your index:

```
<base href="/app1/">
```

from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-run-multiple-node-application-with-nginx-same-droplet-same-domain

Answer (score 2):

This should be solved in the NodeJS applications. Most well-written applications allow you to specify the root url the application will be hosted at and use this to generate all local urls, so I suggest you do the same for your application.

Comment: I had a similar challenge and this exactly the solution. The NodeJS aaplication needs to know it's correct external root in order to generate the correct dynamic URLs at runtime.